# HI~ I am wondering if there is a method to require a PHP file in an echo

Tags: php

i am wondering if there is a method to require another php file in an echo like this:

```
<?php
        echo "
        <label>Post Notifications</label>
        <div>
        <?php require_once('libraries/notifications/post_notifications.php'); ?>
        </div>";
?>

I know the <?php require_once('libraries/notifications/post_notifications.php'); ?> isn't correct but just hope you can get the idea. Thank you!
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? most answer below are correct in sense what they understand, but seems you are looking something else. Please explain your question better.

Comment: Everything also depends what's inside `post_notifications.php` file. What it is doing? Is code inside a function/class or it's simple structural code?

Comment: Putting `<?php` in a string doesn't have any special meaning. That's only meaningful when you're outside a PHP code block, it puts you back into PHP execution mode.

Comment: I am sorry if you don't get the meaning, but it seems that someone got the idea about what i am doing. Why so mean to put a down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ob_get_contents`. Everyting between this tags is stored in variable end cleaned.

```
ob_start();

include('libraries/notifications/post_notifications.php');

$output = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

So this Looks output like:

```
<?php
echo "
  <label>Post Notifications</label>
  <div>
    {$output}
  </div>
";
?>
```